# Call to undefined function shmop_open()

Tags: php, shared-memory, whm

I cannot seem to access any shared memory functions.

I'm running PHP7.1, provisioned using Easy Apache 4.

From what I can make of the documentation shmop should just be there by default. I don't see any specific extension options in Easy Apache that seem relevant to shared memory.

Here's the Configure Command as shown by phpinfo()m which appears to include the required **--enable-shmop**...

```
'./configure' '--build=x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu' '--host=x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu' '--target=x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu' '--program-prefix=' '--prefix=/opt/cpanel/ea-php71/root/usr' '--exec-prefix=/opt/cpanel/ea-php71/root/usr' '--bindir=/opt/cpanel/ea-php71/root/usr/bin' '--sbindir=/opt/cpanel/ea-php71/root/usr/sbin' '--sysconfdir=/opt/cpanel/ea-php71/root/etc' '--datadir=/opt/cpanel/ea-php71/root/usr/share' '--includedir=/opt/cpanel/ea-php71/root/usr/include' '--libdir=/opt/cpanel/ea-php71/root/usr/lib64' '--libexecdir=/opt/cpanel/ea-php71/root/usr/libexec' '--localstatedir=/opt/cpanel/ea-php71/root/usr/var' '--sharedstatedir=/opt/cpanel/ea-php71/root/usr/com' '--mandir=/opt/cpanel/ea-php71/root/usr/share/man' '--infodir=/opt/cpanel/ea-php71/root/usr/share/info' '--cache-file=../config.cache' '--with-libdir=lib64' '--with-config-file-path=/opt/cpanel/ea-php71/root/etc' '--with-config-file-scan-dir=/opt/cpanel/ea-php71/root/etc/php.d' '--disable-debug' '--with-pic' '--without-pear' '--with-bz2' '--with-freetype-dir=/usr' '--with-png-dir=/usr' '--with-xpm-dir=/usr' '--enable-gd-native-ttf' '--without-gdbm' '--with-gettext' '--with-iconv' '--with-jpeg-dir=/usr' '--with-openssl' '--with-zlib' '--with-layout=GNU' '--enable-exif' '--enable-ftp' '--enable-sockets' '--with-kerberos' **'--enable-shmop'** '--with-libxml-dir=/usr' '--with-system-tzdata' '--with-mhash' '--libdir=/opt/cpanel/ea-php71/root/usr/lib64/php' '--enable-pcntl' '--enable-opcache' '--disable-opcache-file' '--enable-phpdbg' '--with-imap=shared,/opt/cpanel/ea-php71/root/usr' '--with-imap-ssl' '--enable-mbstring=shared' '--enable-mbregex' '--with-gd=shared' '--with-gmp=shared' '--enable-calendar=shared' '--enable-bcmath=shared' '--with-bz2=shared' '--enable-ctype=shared' '--enable-dba=shared' '--with-db4=/usr' '--with-tcadb=/usr' '--enable-exif=shared' '--enable-ftp=shared' '--with-gettext=shared' '--with-iconv=shared' '--enable-sockets=shared' '--enable-tokenizer=shared' '--with-xmlrpc=shared' '--with-ldap=shared' '--with-ldap-sasl' '--enable-mysqlnd=shared' '--with-mysqli=shared,mysqlnd' '--with-mysql-sock=/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock' '--enable-dom=shared' '--with-pgsql=shared' '--enable-simplexml=shared' '--enable-xml=shared' '--enable-wddx=shared' '--with-snmp=shared,/usr' '--enable-soap=shared' '--with-xsl=shared,/usr' '--enable-xmlreader=shared' '--enable-xmlwriter=shared' '--with-curl=shared,/opt/cpanel/libcurl' '--enable-pdo=shared' '--with-pdo-odbc=shared,unixODBC,/usr' '--with-pdo-mysql=shared,mysqlnd' '--with-pdo-pgsql=shared,/usr' '--with-pdo-sqlite=shared,/usr' '--with-sqlite3=shared,/usr' '--enable-json=shared' '--enable-zip=shared' '--without-readline' '--with-libedit' '--with-pspell=shared' '--enable-phar=shared' '--with-mcrypt=shared,/opt/cpanel/libmcrypt' '--with-tidy=shared,/opt/cpanel/libtidy' '--enable-sysvmsg=shared' '--enable-sysvshm=shared' '--enable-sysvsem=shared' **'--enable-shmop=shared'** '--enable-posix=shared' '--with-unixODBC=shared,/usr' '--enable-intl=shared' '--with-icu-dir=/usr' '--with-enchant=shared,/usr' '--with-recode=shared,/usr' '--enable-fileinfo=shared' 'build_alias=x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu' 'host_alias=x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu' 'target_alias=x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu'
```

Any suggestions as to what I can try / check?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

After some digging, I found that the *php-shm* extension is in the *common* package (which was installed), BUT it seems to rely on some of the *sysv* extensions which are in the *process* package (which wasn't installed).

Once I added the *process* package the *shmop* functions started working.

Hope this helps someone else.

Answer (score 0):

Just to summarize @xtempore's answer,

In CentOS 8, run:

```
dnf -y install php-process
```